# appending string with integer values python re

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-processing

I was trying to insert a date into a string, using regular expression in python

```
link = 'branch=;deps=;date=;rev=;days=1;user='
date = "10.12.2016"
re.sub(r'(.*)(date=[^;]*)(.*)','\\1\\2'+date+'\\3',link)
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
'branch=;deps=;date=10.12.2016;rev=;days=1;user='
```

but I got this instead,

```
'branch=;deps=;**\x88.12.2016**;rev=;days=1;user='
```

Another thing if I have some character string in the date variable, it is replacing just fine.

```
date="hello"
re.sub(r'(.*)(date=[^;]*)(.*)','\\1\\2'+date+'\\3',link)
```

gives,

```
'branch=;deps=;**date=hello**;rev=;days=1;user='
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why make it difficult?  Skip `re`:

```
>>> link = 'branch=;deps=;date=;rev=;days=1;user='
>>> date = "10.12.2016"
>>> link = link.replace('date=','date='+date)
>>> link
'branch=;deps=;date=10.12.2016;rev=;days=1;user='
```

Or with `re`, but basically the same thing:

```
>>> re.sub(r'date=','date='+date,link)
'branch=;deps=;date=10.12.2016;rev=;days=1;user='
```

The error in your script, was `'\\1\\2'+date+'\\3'` evaluates to `'\\1\\210.12.2016\\3'`.  `'\\210'` evaluates as an octal escape, which is equivalent to `'\x88'`.  You can fix that by using the `\g<n>` sequence:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.*)(date=[^;]*)(.*)','\\1\\g<2>'+date+'\\3',link)
'branch=;deps=;date=10.12.2016;rev=;days=1;user='
```